# $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{x^2 + 2xy - x + y^2 -y - 6} {x + y - 3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've been looking at this multivariable limit for a while and have no idea what trick I am supposed to use. The textbook's supposed answer is 5 which implies the limit does exist, but I have no idea how to get the denominator to cancel with something at the top. I've tried factoring, I've tried limit rules, I have no idea what to do. I would greatly appreciate any hints as to what I should be trying.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$x^2+2xy-x+y^2-y-6=(x+y)^2-(x+y)-6 $$
Can you see the factorization now?

Comment: Yes! This makes perfect sense. Thank you!